# Binding to class properties and fetching to array - php mysqli bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli, bind, prepare

Im trying something like this:

```
class kategoria
{
    public $IdKat;
    public $IdKatNad;
    public $NazwaKat;
}

function get_cats()  
{  

    $query = "SELECT IdKat, NazwaKat, OpisKat  FROM `kategorie`"; 

    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        //$stmt->bind_param("i", $idKat);

        $stmt->execute();
        $kat = new kategoria();

        $stmt->bind_result(
                $kat->Idkat, 
                $kat->NazwaKat, 
                $kat->OpisKat
                );


        $output = array();

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $output += array(clone $kat);
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e;
    }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

At the end - i have only last row in array. Why? When i tried with array (and 2 fields), without "kategoria" class - it worked, but i need to put query result in array of objects representing table rows. what im doing wrong? Im new in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to serialize and deserialize my class binded to result set.

```
$output += array(deserialize(serialize($kat)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output += array(clone $kat);
```

If you're trying to append to the `$output` array the syntax is.

```
$output[] = array(clone $kat); // or array_push($output, array(clone $kat));
```

Adding arrays together in PHP merges them which doesn't seem like what you want.

Comment: Some further reading: array_merge() vs array union operator: http://unix0.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/php-array_merge-vs-plus-union-operator/

Comment: I have two doubts here.Why are you using array(clone $kat).Shouldn't it be just ' = clone $kat'.And cloning only does shallow copy.So will this code work in above case?

Comment: @WordsWorth I just used the same assignment that was in the OP's code. I have no idea what his intentions with it are since he's just `print_r()`'ing it.

Comment: array_push is working, array grows, but now i have many objects created from only last row of table. Clone doesnt work? I need to make variables inside my while loop?

Comment: @Kamil Because you're looping over the results but cloning the same `$kat` object over and over. You need to assign `$kat` in the loop so it changes before it's appended to the array.

Comment: Its the same because im using binding result.

Comment: When i used "the same" variable or array in loop - it worked.

Comment: I found answer in PHP help.

I had to create "deep copy" like this:

       $clone = unserialize(serialize($object));

Because (i believe) PHP help says about clone something like this:

"Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references."